# grounding measurement methods

Tags: measurement, grounding, security, equipment

As long as I know the accepted methods for measuring the resistivity of electric grounding grids, once they are built, for any kind of building (in cities, at industrial level, transmission towers, etc) are:

- Fall of potential using 3 stakes (I have seen this method the most)
- Using a clamp-on tester and rods.
- All sort of, in my opinion, unreliable 'things' using normal testers and cooper bars.

Does anybody know about other methods which are accepted according to norms or at least reliable enough?

Answer (score 1):

You could go with the DIN EN 61557 norm. Part 5 defines measurement requirements and probably also setups for measuring earth resistance in already built structures:

> *Electrical safety in low voltage distribution systems up to 1000 V
>   a.c. and 1500 V d.c. - Equipment for testing, measuring or monitoring
>   of protective measures - Part 5: Resistance to earth*

If you are not from the E.U. the IEC equivalent should be found in [IEC 61557-5](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/5579).

Comment: Thanks a lot Stefan, I will check those norms. I hope someone can have more light about the methods themselves.